# Integrate TAPI with M S CRM2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, tapi

I have requirement of integrating CRM2011 with TAPI3.0.
I am very new to integrations. Can any one tell me how to proceed? For this we are using Ericossons TAPI Bridge.and Astra's Phone box server.
I have installed BusinessLink for windows server, Client and TAPI Bridge3.0 in my sytem. Then
what code do I need to write and where can I write this code?

My Requirement is when customers calls, CRM server should check the phone number in the contact details and if exist open the perticular contacts record.

Please reply if any one have idea/worked already.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm looking at the same thing now. TIA

Answer (score 0):

The solution would involve creating a Windows based utility running on the Client's desktop PC.

I would create the following :-

1) You have some mechanism to either poll, or capture an event from the TAPI interface when a phone call arrives which is intercepted by your utility.

2) Based on the data in the TAPI event query MSCRM using OData or WebServices to determine the record you require.  Return the GUID of the record.

3) Launch on the Client PC an IE window with querystrings of the GUID (there are examples in the SDK for launching records with querystrings).

The utility will need to run in the system tray (or as a service) on all the PCs.  You will need to build an install to deploy the utility to the PCs.

Thanks
Glenn

Comment: Hi thnaks for reply,if u know can you tell me how to get caller id/phone number from tapi.dll(if u have any sample code pls send me)

Answer (score 0):

I have app running in system tray and it sends caller ID via Windows message to chosen app. If you can receive Windows message it will work.